# AngularJS testing controller with jasmine and spyOn gives error 'method undefined'

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, testing, jasmine

So I am writing unit tests for an application in angularJS using Jasmine.

I have a controller with an "init" method which calls "secondMethod" and "thirdMethod"

I want to test with a jasmine spyOn whether "secondMethod" is called correctly.

My controller looks like this:

```
function init() {
    secondMethod().then(function () {
        thirdMethod();
    });
}

init();

function secondMethod(){
    //do something
}

function thirdMethod(){
    //do something
}
```

and my test file looks like this:

```
describe("nameOfTheController", function () {
var $rootScope,
    $controller,
    $scope,
    controller;

beforeEach(function () {

    angular.mock.module("myModule");

    inject(function (_$controller_, _$rootScope_) {
        $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
        $controller = _$controller_;
        $scope = $rootScope.$new();
        controller = $controller('nameOfTheController', {
            '$scope': $scope
        });
    });
});

describe("init", function(){
    it('should run secondMethod', function(){
        spyOn(controller, 'secondMethod');
        expect(controller.secondMethod).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
    it('should run thirdMethod', function(){
        spyOn(controller, 'thirdMethod');
        expect(controller.thirdMethod).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
```

As you can see I inject the controller in beforeEach but I get error that method "secondMethod" and "thirdMethod" are not defined and I am not quite sure why.

I have also tried doing something like the following but to no avail

controller:

```
var vm = this;
vm.init = function() {
    vm.secondMethod().then(function () {
        vm.thirdMethod();
    });
}

vm.init();

vm.secondMethod = function(){
    //do something
}

vm.thirdMethod = function(){
    //do something
}
```

testfile:

```
describe("nameOfTheController", function () {
var $rootScope,
    $controller,
    $scope,
    controller;

beforeEach(function () {

    angular.mock.module("myModule");

    inject(function (_$controller_, _$rootScope_) {
        $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
        $controller = _$controller_;
        $scope = $rootScope.$new();
        controller = $controller('nameOfTheController', {
            '$scope': $scope
        });
    });
});

describe("init", function(){
    it('should run secondMethod', function(){
        spyOn(controller, 'secondMethod');
        expect(controller.secondMethod).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
    it('should run thirdMethod', function(){
        spyOn(controller, 'thirdMethod');
        expect(controller.thirdMethod).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
```

Does anyone know why second and third method are undefined?

**EDIT:**

The reason why second and third method returned undefined when prefixing with "vm." was that the init function was called *before* the second and third method had been defined.

Moving the call of init to be below the second and third method definitions solved the problem. Now I just have the problem that the spy expects the method to be called but it doesn't get called

```
var vm = this;
vm.init = function() {
    vm.secondMethod().then(function () {
        vm.thirdMethod();
    });
}

vm.secondMethod = function(){
    //do something
}

vm.thirdMethod = function(){
    //do something
}

vm.init();
```

Comment: Have you tried to define functions like `$scope.secondMethod = function(){}` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The controller is initiated in `beforeEach()`, and that is when you `init()` => `seconMethod()`, while you spy on it only in the `it()` block.

On the other hand, you can't spy before, since you won't have the controller object.

IMO, the solution will be to revise your code and call init() explicitally:

```
it('should run secondMethod', function() {
    spyOn(controller, 'secondMethod');
    expect(controller.secondMethod).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
    controller.init();
    expect(controller.secondMethod).toHaveBeenCalled();

});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ronapelbaum/v9vyLpws/